# How can I delete rest of the line after a specific string?

Tags: script, notepad++, macros

I'm looking for a way to search for a specific string e.g. '=UUID:' and delete it and all following characters per line. I would prefer a way/macro/addon for notepad++. But all other tools or scripts are welcome :)

Before

```
 *://81.88.22.6/*=UUID:63969B2469B7A94EBBDBD7CB5B9C00BA
 *://*-ad.cgi*=UUID:3C8EFF48B674CC42BF5B6E2B7BA820E7
 *://*-ads/*=UUID:0D6CF7D5BE3F034C8A136CC99A074406
```

Note that the numbers are always different per line so you couldn't do a search 'n replace with them.

Should look like this after

```
*://81.88.22.6/*
*://*-ad.cgi*
*://*-ads/*
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Search mode *regular expression*, Find

```
=UUID:.*
```

Replace with nothing.

Comment: The point between both expressions did the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nixdagibts that's not a "point between both expressions". It searches for `=UUID:`, followed by any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`), effectively "any sequence of characters", ending at the line break.

Comment: @nixdagibts you could, in the future, try `=UUID:[0-9A-F]{32}` to prevent false positives (i.e. removing something you'd want to keep)

Answer (score 5):

It's easy.  Your question:

```
*://81.88.22.6/*=UUID:63969B2469B7A94EBBDBD7CB5B9C00BA
*://*-ad.cgi*=UUID:3C8EFF48B674CC42BF5B6E2B7BA820E7
*://*-ads/*=UUID:0D6CF7D5BE3F034C8A136CC99A074406
```

My answer:

```
[=].*
```

Result:

```
*://81.88.22.6/*
*://*-ad.cgi*
*://*-ads/*
```

Explanation:

> = character, represent the character you want to remove
>   .* characters, represent all the characters after that

That's it.

Comment: Basically the same as Daniel's answer. He's suggest searching for `=UUID:` and delete the rest of the line with `.*`. You minimized it by only searching for the first character `=`. Additionally there's no need to use a capture group `[]`

Answer (score -2):

Using find and replace:

1. Hit CTRL-H to open the Replace dialogue box
2. enter `=UUID:.*` into Find what
3. leave Replace with empty
4. Select Regular expression and .matches newline
5. Click on Replace

Comment: You are replicating another answer